# ANDROID: Is it possible to talk with a bluetooth headset like a walkie talkie?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Is it possible to write an Android application that let me use a paired bluetooth headset like a walkie talkie?

So I can talk on the phone's mic and another person can listen from the headset and he can do the same, talk on the headset mic and I can listen on the phone?
If it is possible any piece of code to demonstrate it will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @lorenzop, I know some time has passed since you asked, but just in case: have you found a solution or an already existing app for this?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of the question, it is technically possible to do this. You can try [Voxer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebelvox.voxer) app but not all bluetooth headsets are compatible (https://support.voxer.com/entries/26835368-What-headsets-and-bluetooth-devices-does-Live-Interrupt-Mode-Support-).

Comment: Per my understanding, Voxer enables walkie talkie feature with other devices/phones, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, Android of course but also iOS, Windows Phone and Chrome. They transmit the message directly from one device to another and also record it on the device so it can be replayed if needed.

Comment: @Louis I think the questions was whether Voxer allows walkie-talkie-like communication *between a phone and a BT headset connected to that phone*, rather than just use the headset as part of one side of the communication. The description 'send and receive voxes handsfree from a bluetooth or wired headset, even if the Voxer app is closed and the phone is locked" says no such thing, and few of us feel like creating an account on an app privileged to send SMS just to check that.